# Timing belt replacement

Tags: volvo, timing-belt, s60

We picked up a 2006 Volvo s60 from a friends mother.  It only had 22k miles when we got it.  It had sat idle outside for 3 years prior to us getting it.  We changed all fluids, brakes and tires.  It’s running great, now approaching 30k miles.  I know timing belts usually go to 100k or so.  Since it is older, should we think about replacing the timing belt now?  Any way to tell if it needs replacing?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yes; Volvo service documentation lists either 10 or 15 years as the time limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. [Volvo service documentation](https://www.volvotechinfo.com/index.cfm?event=viewFile&fileName=TimingBeltInterval.pdf&hash=826D4D811420457F286DA2D6848C60A2) lists either 10 or 15 years as the time limit.

Probably not. Unless the belt is obviously cut or abraded or shredding, there are no visual clues. Because this motor is an interference design, belt failure will result in the pistons bouncing off and destroying the valves. At the very least, this would be an expensive repair, and replacing the entire cylinder head or the motor might then be sensible.

Remember to also change the tensioner and idle pulley.